# Convergence of series $\cos (x/2) + \cos (x/2^2) + \cdots + \cos (x/2^m)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have been told that $$\lim_{m\to \infty}\left(\cos (x/2) + \cos (x/2^2) + \cdots + \cos (x/2^m)\right)=\frac{x}{\sin (x)}$$

I tried working with the power series of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ but it becomes messy pretty soon. I was hoping that there might be some trick to arrive at such a conclusion. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry to break the spell but the limit of the sum in the LHS is +infinity, for every x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answers what I think is probably the question the OP has in mind, which is not at present the question they asked.*

Consider, for every $x$ and every $n\geqslant0$,
$$
f_n(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n\cos(x/2^k).
$$
Then, using repeatedly the identity $\sin(2t)=2\sin(t)\cos(t)$, a recursion on $n\geqslant0$ yields
$$
2^n\sin(x/2^n)f_n(x)=\sin(x).
$$
When $n\to\infty$, for every $x\ne0$, $2^n\sin(x/2^n)\to x$. Furthermore, $f_n(0)=1$ for every $n$ hence, for every $x$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\frac{\sin x}x.
$$

Comment: But the OP asked about $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(x/2^k)$

Comment: @DennisGulko Yes, the present version of the question is absurd on several counts, which is why *This answers what I think is probably the question the OP has in mind, which is not at present the question they asked.*

Comment: Yes, you are right. The limit the OP asked does not exist.

Comment: @DennisGulko As I saw fit to indicate in a comment to the question. :-)

Comment: thank you :) i guess you must be right

Answer (score 0):

You can use $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$, then you should be able to see that the sum on the left side has a remarkable similarity to the fact that $$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)...=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: Sorry but I am unable *to see that the sum on the left side has a remarkable similarity to the fact* you mention

Answer (score 0):

Try to substitute $\cos(x/2^n)=\sin(x/2^{n-1})/(2\sin(x/2^n))$, then you obtain a telescopic product.